# How to sort/filter django model fields in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is a model for a product database. It occurred to me when rendering the products on a template that there are products that are the same just with different measurements. Is there a way to group these products together, so that the items don't repeat themselves.

```
class Product(models.Model):
      product_code = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
      type = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
      product = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
      standard = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
      measurement = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
      brand = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', null=True, blank=True)
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)

     class Meta:
          verbose_name_plural = "Product"
          ordering = ["id"]
     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('product')
     def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s  %s' % (self.id, self.product_code, self.type, 
                                self.product, self.standard, 
                                self.measurement, self.brand, self.photo, self.price)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between two Products is *measurement*, one solution would be to abstract measurement to

> a. An options tuple (eg, options=MEASUREMENTS), or
>
> b. A Measurement model and relate the two, eg, measurement=models.ForeignKey(…)

It really depends on how many possible measurements you might have. If there are only 3-5, a tuple would work fine. If anything is possible, a Model would make the most sense I think.

After you've done this, you can consolidate the similar products to a single product, thus eliminating duplicates in our template output.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, its definitely more than 3-5. What do i do with the current data in the fields. Also each product has a unique product code associated with it.

Comment: OK, so what you are saying is that they really are unique products but they are similar and the primary difference is the measurements. Is the product code like a SKU? Some examples of data might really help with this...especially two _similar_ products with differing measurements where you don't want both listed.

Comment: Hey im having difficultly in explaining this. here is a screen shoot of the product list in excel. I hope this helps :
[Excel Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4d4RhPuJVGMN3RPVXphbnBOWjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The screenshot gives some good examples of the data. Does the database look exactly like this? If so, the challenge is going to be that there is a lot of repetition there. I think you would probably want a normalized DB with separate models for Brand, Standard, etc. Or, as I said about measurements, if there are only a few Brands, for instance, you might just put them in a tuple and use the `options` argument (eg, `options=(('AZEETA','AZEETA'),('EURATECH','EURATECH'))`). Still, without knowing more about the meaning of the data columns, I can't really advise you on how to structure the data.